# How do I export an InfoPath form to PDF or XLS?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, infopath

We have an InfoPath 2010 form connected to a SharePoint 2010 list.

Users need to import data into the form/list, but also need to export the form to PDF/XLS to save in a third-party application. We cannot directly connect to that application - it needs to be a file upload.

InfoPath is not permitting us to add a custom code that would export the form, such as:

```
this.CurrentView.Export(@"C:\MyView.pdf", ExportFormat.Pdf);
```

Are there any alternative approaches that we can consider, or ways in which we can embed the appropriate code?

Answer (score 0):

there is 3rd party tool called Muhimbi PDF Converter http://blog.muhimbi.com/2012/02/convert-infopath-to-ms-word-excel-xps.html

or there is an other way is create a HarePoint workflow which convert it into the PDF.

[Convert InfoPath form to PDF with SharePoint workflow](https://www.harepoint.com/Products/HarePointWorkflowExtensions/SharePoint-InfoPath-PDF-Conversion.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Unfortunately we cannot install third-party tools on our server. Any other thoughts or suggestions would be welcome.